# getting error while trying to get value from redis if key is not exist

Tags: redis, elixir, phoenix-framework

```
{_, value} = Redix.command(:redix, ["GET", socket.assigns.user])
```

This Command fails if there is no record available in the Redis database

This is the error display in the console 
[

```
 [error] GenServer #PID<0.461.0> terminating
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in PhoenixChat.RoomChannel.handle_info/2
    (phoenix_chat) web/channels/room_channel.ex:14: PhoenixChat.RoomChannel.handle_info(%Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "message:new", payload: %{body: %{"to" => "rusiru", "value" => "hi bro "}, timestamp: 1501498879699, user: "abc"}, topic: "room:rusiru"}, %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{user: "abc"}, channel: PhoenixChat.RoomChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.461.0>, endpoint: PhoenixChat.Endpoint, handler: PhoenixChat.UserSocket, id: nil, joined: true, pubsub_server: PhoenixChat.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocketSerializer, topic: "room:abc", transport: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, transport_name: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.421.0>})
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/channel/server.ex:239: Phoenix.Channel.Server.handle_info/2
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:601: :gen_server.try_dispatch/4
    (stdlib) gen_server.erl:667: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: %Phoenix.Socket.Broadcast{event: "message:new", payload: %{body: %{"to" => "rusiru", "value" => "hi bro "}, timestamp: 1501498879699, user: "abc"}, topic: "room:rusiru"}
State: %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{user: "abc"}, channel: PhoenixChat.RoomChannel, channel_pid: #PID<0.461.0>, endpoint: PhoenixChat.Endpoint, handler: PhoenixChat.UserSocket, id: nil, joined: true, pubsub_server: PhoenixChat.PubSub, ref: nil, serializer: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocketSerializer, topic: "room:abc", transport: Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, transport_name: :websocket, transport_pid: #PID<0.421.0>}
[info] JOIN room:abc to PhoenixChat.RoomChannel
  Transport:  Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
  Parameters: %{}
[info] Replied room:abc :ok
```

This is the code snippet in `room_channel.ex`

```
 def handle_info(:after_join, socket) do
     {_, value} = Redix.command(:redix, ["GET", socket.assigns.user])
    Presence.track(socket, socket.assigns.user, %{
      online_at: :os.system_time(:millisecond),
      status: value
    })
    push socket, "presence_state", Presence.list(socket)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Which line is line 32 of `user_socket.ex`? The error is not due to the return value of that function. Something is calling `String.trim/1` on `nil`. Maybe `socket.assigns.user` is nil?

Comment: def connect(%{"user" => user, "status" => status}, socket) do
    #Redix.command(:redix, ["SET", user, status]) 
   #{_, value} = Redix.command(:redix, ["GET", user]) 
    if (String.strip(status) == "" ) do
      {_, value} = Redix.command(:redix, ["GET", user]) 
      if (String.strip(value) == "") do
        Redix.command(:redix, ["SET", user, "online"])
      end
    else
      {_, value} = Redix.command(:redix, ["GET", user]) 
      if (String.strip(value) == String.strip(status))do#32line
      else
         Redix.command(:redix, ["SET", user, status])
      end
    end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GET` command will not return an error if the key is not present. It'll return `{:ok, nil}` instead:

```
iex(1)> {:ok, conn} = Redix.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.159.0>}
iex(2)> Redix.command(conn, ["GET", "key-that-doesnt-exist"])
{:ok, nil}
```

So your pattern match succeeds but the returned value is `nil`, which you later pass to `String.trim/1` which throws the error you're getting.

You can handle the key not existing case like this:

```
case Redix.command(:redix, ["GET", socket.assigns.user]) do
  {:ok, nil} -> # key doesn't exist
  {:ok, value} -> # key exists, value is in `value`
  {:error, error} -> # some other error
end
```